# Array of strings in Knockout

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, knockout.js

I am working on an ASP MVC chess web app. The server-client part are made with SignalR. The server part is made in C#, where the game is implemented, and the client part is in javascript using Knockout.

For the chess board there are 64 img tags. The source paths for those images are stored in a list of strings in the client part. Using SignalR I can pass that array to the client.

I am having problems binding that array to my images, I cannot use data-bind="foreach: pathArray" because those img tags have different css classes (white / black) and different ID's. Therefore I am trying to bind the source to the paths like this

```
data-bind="attr: { src: pathArray()[1]}"
```

but it doesn't work.

Debugging in Chrome, I saw that the array in javascript is populated but I cannot bind item from it to the img tags.

Is there another way to do this? Like another javascript library?

EDIT:
This is how I declared it.
    self.CellList = ko.observableArray([]);

This is how I put data in it.

```
for (i = 0; i < cellList.length; i++) {
            viewModel.CellList.push(cellList[i]);
        }
```

where cellList is a string array received from SignalR.

```
hub.client.beginGame = function (gameDetails, cellList)
```

Comment: Is your `pathArray` an observable array? (`ko.observableArray`) If it isn't, you don't need to use the parentheses.

Comment: Please include an [mcve] in your post. Without a way to reproduce your problem we can only guess at the solution.

Comment: Are you sure you're binding it correctly? For example, this is how would you get result from regular array vs observable array in KO: https://jsfiddle.net/kasperoo/gtb2L0m5/ But it would be very laborious for you, to manually specify each cell with an index of an array. Wouldn't it be better to still create mini object for each cell, to which you can pass in parameters such as ID, class names and urls?

Comment: You haven't provided enough code to debug your issue, please recreate your problem in a jsFiddle

Comment: Can you give me an example of those mini objects? Are you talking about mini objects in razor?  I updated the posts with example code.

Comment: @QBM5 That array string is being received from a c# server every time is a function is called, I don't know how to recreate that in jsFiddle. I think my problem is that I somehow don't assign that array well. I tried with a simple string and it doesn't work

    viewModel.Valoare = "Work";

and to show it:

    <span data-bind="text: Valoare"></span>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more code it is hard to tell what the problem is but instead of inserting the strings directly I would create a vm for each item in "cellList"

```
var cell = function(data,index){
    var self = this;

    self.class = index%2==0?'black':'white';
    self.id = 'prefix'+data.id
}
```

Having logic in the view is nothing but trouble. Pulling it out to a vm solves a lot of issues.